# Catch Apple Remote events in webbrowser with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

Is there a chance to use the Apple Remote with my web browser (Safari, Chrome or Firefox)? For example, my HTML page makes a transition if I click the right or left arrow. I want to cause this transition not only by pressing a key but also by clicking on my Apple Remote (which is usually used with Frontrow).

The condensed question is: do I have the chance to catch Apple Remote events with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

theres a few ways of doing that, one eould be to use max msp or pure data as a socket client to http://socket.io then capture the apple remote on max or pd and send the events to the socket server. another way would be finding a plugin for the browser that is able to interface between the controller and the javascript running in the current tab.